# TypeScript: annotate ES5 generic class

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, typedoc

I have the following code, in a file named `storage.ts`. Its purpose is to serve as a storage device for multiple parts of my API.

```
interface ICache<T> {
  [key: string]: T
}

declare class Cacher<T> {
  constructor (initialCache: ICache<T>)
  define (key: string, val: T): void
  get (key: string): T
  remove (key: string): void
  clear (): void
  load (cacheObj: ICache<T>): void
}

function Cacher<T> (this: any, initialCache: ICache<T>) {
  var cache: ICache<T> = initialCache
  this.define = function (key: string, val: T) {
    cache[key] = val
  }
  this.get = function (key: string) {
    if (cache[key]) {
      return cache[key]
    } else {
      throw new Error ("Key '" + key + "' doesn't exist")
    }
  }
  this.remove = function (key: string) {
    delete cache[key]
  }
  this.clear = function () {
    cache = {}
  }
  this.load = function (cacheObj: ICache<T>) {
    cache = cacheObj
  }
}

export default Cacher
```

Usage example (`containers.ts`):

```
import Cacher from './storage'
type TemplateFunction = (options: object, config: object) => string

var Templates = new Cacher<TemplateFunction>({})
```

Everything is all fine and great, VSCode and TSLint don't throw any errors, etc., until I try and build with TypeDoc. Then, `containers.ts` gives this error:

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

and `storage.ts` gives this error twice, on line 6 and 15:

> Duplicate identifier 'Cacher'

I might think this was just an issue with TypeDoc, but changing `function Cacher<T> (this: any, initialCache: ICache<T>) {` to `export default function Cacher<T> (this: any, initialCache: ICache<T>) {` and removing the last line gives this error:

> Merged declaration 'Cacher' cannot include a default export declaration. Consider adding a separate 'export default Cacher' declaration instead.ts(2652)

I've spent hours trying to fix this. I've tried multiple different variations of [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237064/how-to-implement-a-typescript-interface-to-an-es5-style-class), but it doesn't allow for passing in a generic. Besides, I find `let x = function()` to be a lot less elegant than `function x()`.

Random notes:

- I replaced `this: any` with `this: [an interface that represents this]`. Same issue as before
- For reasons I'd rather not go into, I do not want to convert it to a class
- Possibly related to this error: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3973

I'd love any help - sorry for the long post!

Comment: Is `new Storage<TemplateFunction>({})` a typo?  What's `Storage`?

Comment: @jcalz oops, typo. It was supposed to say `new Cacher<...`

Comment: Sounds like the same file is being included multiple times (or perhaps the ts file and its js output are both being included).  Possible duplicate of [Confusing “duplicate identifier” Typescript error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322525/confusing-duplicate-identifier-typescript-error-message)

Comment: @jcalz perhaps. The errors are on different lines, though, and come from the `.ts` files. Followed the fixes in the link you posted JIC, but no luck